# Deleting a Group of Fields from an Admin

Tags: php, forms, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-3.3

I tried to follow Sonata UserBundle group and row deletion method which is explained here : [Official Doc Sonata](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/cookbook/recipe_delete_field_group.html)

However if I do that nothing happens so I searched a bit on the internet but I did not find anything about it. I tried to add this :

```
sonata_user:

    security_acl: true
    manager_type: orm
    admin:
        user:
            class:          Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Admin\UserAdmin
            controller:     SonataAdminBundle:CRUD
```

But then I come out with a big error:

> The autoloader expected class "Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Admin\UserAdmin" to be defined in file "C:\wamp64\www\WebBundle\vendor\composer/../../src\Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Admin\UserAdmin.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.

I also tried to put file in AppBundle but I find myself with the same error, without putting `admin : user:` in the config.yml file:

> The autoloader expected class "AppBundle\Admin\UserAdmin" to be defined in file "C:\wamp64\www\WebBundle\vendor\composer/../../src\AppBundle\Admin\UserAdmin.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo in C:\wamp64\www\WebBundle\app/config\services.yml (which is being imported from "C:\wamp64\www\WebBundle\app/config\config.yml").

Comment: Yep i'm working with composer 1.4.1, I'm running it on wamp on my computer in localhost

Comment: new Sonata\EasyExtendsBundle\SonataEasyExtendsBundle(),
            new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
            new Sonata\UserBundle\SonataUserBundle(),
            new Application\Sonata\UserBundle\ApplicationSonataUserBundle(),

Comment: Even if i try with new Sonata\UserBundle\SonataUserBundle('FOSUserBundle'), it's not working at all :/ And i was able to log me in and register new profile before i just can't delete fields ...

Comment: And to add i'm using Master version of UserBundle and if you look on the installation part you don't have to put the SonataUserBundle('FOSUserBundle'), according to them

Comment: I am currently working under symfony 3.3 so I do not think I can upgrade to version 3.19 right? Must I re-do my project with an older version of symfony? If yes which one ?

Comment: Fosuser bundle with Sonata UserBundle is not compatible with Symfony 3  ( compatible only with Master version of Sonata UserBundle )

Comment: @Doug I tried to comeback with an older version of Sonata. I'm tried with Sonata 3.2 and it's not working too ... :/ Any idea ?

Comment: Already checked 100 times otherwise I would not have allowed myself to post this question here, I went back to "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "3.19", and "sonata-project/user-bundle": "^3.2", and "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*", to be able to use an other version of userBundle than master one. But still the same error :/

Comment: No idea then sorry. All I can see is in the docs they use Sonata\UserBundle\Admin\Entity\UserAdmin for the **admin** section and the class section **prior** to the admin section uses Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User
 as you can see here: https://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/3-x/doc/reference/advanced_configuration.html

Comment: @Doug 
Do not bother, I'll do without UserBundle I'll do it with my little hand. But thank you very much for your help. It was super nice of you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My only suggestion would be, where you have:

```
sonata_user:    
    security_acl: true
    manager_type: orm
    admin:
        user:
            class:          Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Admin\UserAdmin
            controller:     SonataAdminBundle:CRUD
```

Try the following:

```
sonata_user:
    security_acl:           true

    manager_type: orm
    class:                  # Entity Classes
        user:               Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User
        group:              Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\Group

    admin:                  # Admin Classes
        user:
            class:          Sonata\UserBundle\Admin\Entity\UserAdmin
            controller:     SonataAdminBundle:CRUD
            translation:    SonataUserBundle
```

As described in the [official docs](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/3-x/doc/reference/advanced_configuration.html)

Comment: Nop :/. I will just use my own security stuff thanks a lot for your time !

Comment: I will try to raise this issue to the staff of Sonata maybe it's a bug. Will see

Answer (score 0):

I think i found a solution of that problem for the Master Version, you can go in Vendor/sonata-project/user-bundle/Admin/Model/UserAdmin and directly modify the file so you don't have to use the solution recommended in the documentation.
I hope that will help some people.